# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'username') at LeadAdmin.js:121:1

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

I am Populating 'owner' field from  My 'lead' document in moongose MERN,
it was working perfectly fine but  after somer days  its going on  type erros of reading null
[this is the errror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byAaN.png) 
i am excepting to access the poppulated fields of user from lead (in lead -> owner field)

here my lead.js route

```
router.get('/', auth, (req, res) => {
    User.findById(req.user.id).then((user) => {
        if (user.isadmin) {
            Lead.find({})
                .populate({ path: 'owner', options: { sort: { recieveddate: -1 } } })
                .exec((err, lead) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    // console.log(lead)
                    res.json(lead);
                });
        } else {
            Lead.find({ owner: user._id })
                .sort({ recieveddate: -1 })
                .then((leads) => res.json(leads));
        }
    });
});
```

here my react rendering page
in map funtion

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Table from '@mui/material/Table';
import TableBody from '@mui/material/TableBody';
import TableCell, { tableCellClasses } from '@mui/material/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@mui/material/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@mui/material/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@mui/material/TableRow';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import { Container } from '@mui/material';

import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getLeads, deleteLead } from '../../actions/leadActions'
// import ItemModal from './ItemModal';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Component } from 'react';

import SendMail from '../client/SendMail';

import moment from 'moment';
import DeleteLead from './DeleteLead';
import AssignLead from './AssignLead';
import UpdateLead from './UpdateLead';
import UpdateStatus from '../client/UpdateStatus';
import SendMsg from '../client/SendMsg';

const StyledTableCell = styled(TableCell)(({ theme }) => ({
    [`&.${tableCellClasses.head}`]: {
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.black,
        color: theme.palette.common.white,

    },
    [`&.${tableCellClasses.body}`]: {
        fontSize: 14,

    },
}));

const StyledTableRow = styled(TableRow)(({ theme }) => ({
    '&:nth-of-type(odd)': {
        // backgroundColor: 'green',


    },
    // hide last border
    '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': {
        border: 0,
    },
}));

function createData(fullName, email, phoneNo, leadId, make, model, year, vehicleType, recievedDate, actions) {
    return { fullName, email, phoneNo, leadId, make, model, year, vehicleType, recievedDate, actions };
}

class LeadAdmin extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        lead: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getLeads();
        this.interval = setInterval(() => { this.props.getLeads() }, 1000);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }




    // componentDidUpdate() {
    //     this.props.getLeads();
    // }


    render() {
        const { leads, loading } = this.props.lead;
        const { user } = this.props.auth;

        return (
            <Container sx={{ width: 1400 }}  >

                <TableContainer component={Paper} sx={{ maxHeight: 500, maxWidth: 1600, overflowY: 'scroll' }}  >
                    <Table sx={{ minWidth: 1600 }} aria-label="customized table">
                        <TableHead>
                            <TableRow>
                                <StyledTableCell>FullName </StyledTableCell>
                                <StyledTableCell align="center">Email</StyledTableCell>
                                <StyledTableCell align="center">Phone NO&nbsp;</StyledTableCell>
                                <StyledTableCell align="center">Assigned To&nbsp;</StyledTableCell>
                                <StyledTableCell align="center">Lead Id&nbsp;</StyledTableCell>
                                <StyledTableCell align="center">Make&nbsp;</StyledTableCell>
                                <StyledTableCell align="center">Model&nbsp;</StyledTableCell>
                                <StyledTableCell align="center">Year&nbsp;</StyledTableCell>
                                <StyledTableCell align="center">Vehicle Type&nbsp;</StyledTableCell>
                                <StyledTableCell align="center">Recieved Date&nbsp;</StyledTableCell>
                                <StyledTableCell align="center">Time&nbsp;</StyledTableCell>
                                <StyledTableCell sx={{ width: 300 }} align="center">Actions</StyledTableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableHead>
                        <TableBody>
                            {leads.map((row) => (

                                <StyledTableRow key={row.fullname} sx={row.isassigned ? user.isadmin ? { backgroundColor: '#8EE2B8' } : { backgroundColor: '' } : ''} >

                                    {row.status == 'lead' ?
                                        <>

                                            <StyledTableCell component="th" scope="row">
                                                {row.fullname}

                                            </StyledTableCell>
                                            <StyledTableCell align="center">{row.email}</StyledTableCell>
                                            <StyledTableCell align="center">{row.phoneno}</StyledTableCell>
                                            <StyledTableCell align="center">{row.owner.username?  row.owner.username  : 'N/A'}</StyledTableCell>

                                            <StyledTableCell align="center">{row._id}</StyledTableCell>
                                            <StyledTableCell align="center">{row.make}</StyledTableCell>
                                            <StyledTableCell align="center">{row.model}</StyledTableCell>
                                            <StyledTableCell align="center">{row.modelyear}</StyledTableCell>
                                            <StyledTableCell align="center">{row.vehicletype}</StyledTableCell>
                                            <StyledTableCell align="center">{moment(row.recieveddate).format("ddd, MMM D YYYY")}</StyledTableCell>
                                            <StyledTableCell align="center">{moment(row.recieveddate).format("h:mm a")}</StyledTableCell>
                                            <StyledTableCell align="center"  >
                                                <Stack spacing={2} direction="row">
                                                    {user.isadmin ?
                                                        <>

                                                            <Button variant="contained" sx={{ width: 80, backgroundColor: 'black', borderRadius: 50 }}>Cherry</Button>
                                                            <UpdateLead {...row} />
                                                            <DeleteLead id={row._id} name={row.fullname} />
                                                            <AssignLead leadid={row._id} isassigned={row.isassigned} />
                                                        </>
                                                        :

                                                        <>

                                                            <SendMail email={row.email} />
                                                            <SendMsg  {...row} />
                                                            <Button variant="contained" sx={{ width: 80, backgroundColor: 'black', borderRadius: 50 }} >Orange</Button>
                                                            <UpdateStatus leadid={row._id} />
                                                            <UpdateLead {...row} />
                                                        </>

                                                    }

                                                </Stack>
                                            </StyledTableCell>
                                        </>
                                        : ''}



                                </StyledTableRow>

                            ))}
                        </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                </TableContainer>
            </Container>

        );
    }
}

LeadAdmin.propTypes = {
    getLeads: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    lead: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    lead: state.lead,
    auth: state.auth,

})



export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getLeads })(LeadAdmin);
```

Comment: If `row.owner` is `undefined` then it's `undefined`.  In your debugging, what is the observed value of `row` when the error occurs?  Where/how is it being populated?  The error is happening client-side, but most of the code shown is server-side.  Is the server returning the expected result for this request or not?

Comment: at the server side i do console.log i was getting all populated fields  but in fronted react i do console.log  of response  there owner field is none  whats the problem ?

Comment: The problem is that `row.owner` is `undefined` and the code assumes it won't be.  Now is a good time for you to do some debugging.  Where do you create `row`?  What value do you assign to it?  Where does that value come from?  None of this is indicated in the code shown above.  What you're showing are two entirely separate pieces of code.  You may indeed have verified that the first piece of code above is doing what you expect, but that has no bearing on the second piece of code above which is where the error occurs.

Comment: i have updated the react component code please have a look

Comment: So `row` is an element from the `leads` array.  And the `leads` array comes from: `const { leads, loading } = this.props.lead;`  What `lead` prop are you passing to the component?  What populates it?  When the error occurs, what is the value of that `lead` prop?  How does it differ from what you expect?  Continue your debugging.  *As a guess*, it sounds like you're loading data via AJAX and assuming that data will be loaded before rendering the component, which it won't be.

Comment: hi you are access json to 3 level  row.owner.username, in some row.owner does not have any value

Answer (score 0):

you are accessing json to 3 level row.owner.username, in some row.owner does not have any value i.e is undefined , update your code as below

```
 <StyledTableCell align="center">{row?.owner?.username?  row?.owner?.username  : 'N/A'}</StyledTableCell>
```